# SLD file not being read from ArcGIS Server WMS service

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-10.2, arcgis-server, wms, sld

I am trying to link an external SLD file to my WMS service in ArcGIS Server but it is being ignored.

I have one layer in my MXD called 'Rivers', I then published the layer as WMS service in the ArcGIS Server via ArcMap.

I have checked 'WMS' in the capability tab. In ArcGIS Sever Manager, I navigate to my Service--> Capabilities --> WMS --> SLD Path or URL. I have entered my SLD file path, then restart the service. But, change is not reflecting in the service, it is still using ArcMap style.

I have gone through [this](https://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/publish-services/linux/using-styled-layer-descriptors-with-wms-services.htm) link, but no success.

My service name is "RiverService". I am using version Arc V. 10.8.
Here is my SLD file:

```
<sld:StyledLayerDescriptor xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:sld="http://www.opengis.net/sld"
    xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.0.0"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.0.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd">
    <sld:NamedLayer>
        <sld:Name>Rivers</sld:Name>
        <sld:UserStyle><sld:Name>Rivers</sld:Name>
            <sld:Title>lineSymbolizer</sld:Title>
            <sld:FeatureTypeStyle>
                <sld:Rule>
                    <sld:LineSymbolizer>
                        <sld:Stroke>
                            <sld:CssParameter name="stroke">#FF00FF</sld:CssParameter>
                            <sld:CssParameter name="stroke-opacity">1</sld:CssParameter>
                            <sld:CssParameter name="stroke-width">2</sld:CssParameter>
                        </sld:Stroke>
                    </sld:LineSymbolizer>
                </sld:Rule>
            </sld:FeatureTypeStyle></sld:UserStyle>
    </sld:NamedLayer>
</sld:StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

Comment: In doing the code formatting for easier readability I see there is an error in the line `<sld:UserStyle>Rivers<sld:Name>Rivers</sld:Name>`  the `rivers` text immediately after `<sld:UserStyle>` is incorrect.  Not sure if this is a typo when you posted the question, or the actual issue

Comment: Its a typo error while posting the question.

Comment: Can you give an example of the GetMap request you use to apply the external SLD